# Which Tree traversal String is unique?

Tags: trees, binary-trees, tree-traversal

Assume we have a tree and we want to serialize it.

**Example:**

```
Tree
                              
      1                                                  
     / \                                                
    3   2                                       
   / \ / \                                 
  5  N N  N   
 / \
N   N
```

can result as:

```
"1,3,5,N,N,N,2,N,N", // Pre Order serialization;
"N,5,N,3,N,1,N,2,N", // In Order serialization;
"N,N,5,N,3,N,N,2,1", // Post Order serialization
```

I would like to know, which one of these three serializations is unique for all trees and why ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Preorder traversal:**

This traversals always yield unique binary trees. For a proof, please check [why recording non-existent children in the pre-order traversal will differentiate different binary trees?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/144593/why-recording-non-existent-children-in-the-pre-order-traversal-will-differentiat/144601#144601).

For instance consider traversal sequence $6,5,N,N,5,3,N,N,2,N,N$.

We can proceed as follow to construct binary tree.

> 1. First symbol is always root of tree.

Root will always be identified uniquely.

> 2. Try to parse remaining part of input recursively(This will be our left sub-tree). When one sub-tree is parsed  return.

Here this left sub-tree parsing will start with input $5,N,N,5,3,N,N,2,N,N$ and will return after input $5,3,N,N,2,N,N$ left to be processed.

> 3. Try to parse yet remaining part of input recursively(This will be our right sub-tree).

---

**Post-order traversal**: This is similar to pre-order.

---

**inorder traversal**: This does not always yield unique binary tree. Here is counterexample.

Consider preorder traversal $N,5,N,6,N,3,N,5,N,2,N$. And following two binary trees.

```
        6                    5
       /  \                /  \
      5    5              6    2
     / \  /  \           / \  / \
    N  N 3    2         5   3 N  N
        / \  / \       / \ / \
       N   N N  N     N  N N  N
```

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/serialize-deserialize-binary-tree/   if you look to this, under "How to store a general Binary Tree?" they  write "We can save space by storing Preorder traversal and a marker for NULL pointers" Does it mean that the PREORDER storing N is unique?

Comment: Yes preorder traversal with markers as in this question uniquely determines binary key.